# Search for Google Drive files based on new properties resource

Tags: google-drive-api

Google just introduced a new feature in Google Drive SDK which is the ability to set properties to files, as key/value pairs. 
According to the blog post on Google Developers blog we can use these properties as searchable fields. However I cannot see in the documentation how to search for files using these properties.

For example: retrieve all files where property A has the value X.

I know the feature is brand new but I could really make use of this in my current project. Have I missed anything ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I find, its possible to search on drive based on `properties` param.

Check doc. https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters

Code Snippet :

```
resp = newDriveService.files().list(q="properties has { key='customKeyA' and value='customKeyAValue2' and visibility='PUBLIC' }").execute()
```

Note : you have to specify all 3 params viz. key, value and visibility while searching. If you don't use it will throw Invalid Params exception.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, we don't currently support this. This is currently a high priority for Google and they are working on it. Stay tuned.

Comment: Too bad, I'll wait for this feature then, we have a lot of applications for this. Thanks !

"Apps can also now add custom properties to any Drive file. The new properties collection gives your app the power to create searchable fields that are private to your app or shared across apps."
What does "searchable fields" mean then ?

Comment: It's pretty badly written, sorry. It should mean that "one day you will be able to search them, one day soon." :D

Comment: I'll wait patiently then =p Thx !

Comment: Hi @AliAfshar, any news on the availability of such feature ?

Comment: Its supported now. Please check my answer